# Getting file url from a dropbox file with dropbox api

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I need to get a file listing from a non public folder on dropbox. After this, I need to get an URL for each file to let me access it through http. Is this possible with dropbox api?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out DropboxAPI.Entry metadata() and  DropboxAPI.DropboxLink share() [here](https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.5.3-docs/index.html)

Comment: Is it possible to access Dropbox folder without having to authorize application? I mean, I need a service to show a set of pictures to my users and don't want them to be annoyed with the auth form. Is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: from your own Dropbox? You could get urls by using the share link functionality and then hard code the links in. Dropbox does throttle those links occasionally though.

Comment: What I was lookinf or is a way to list the files and access them. I don't want to hardcode. What a pity. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Dan the link is broken. help!