# Java Dropbox API get public share link after uploading file

Tags: java, dropbox, dropbox-api

The following uploads my file to the specified path in dropbox:

```
DbxEntry.File uploadedFile = client.uploadFile("/" + id + "/name" + ".png",
DbxWriteMode.add(), tile.length(), inputStream);
System.out.println("Uploaded: " + uploadedFile.toString());
```

However how can i **retrieve the Public Share URL after it is uploaded**? I can't find any documentation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942371/getting-file-url-from-a-dropbox-file-with-dropbox-api

Comment: @JamesB Thanks found my answer.

Comment: You may wish to add it here so others can see. Unless of course, it is on the post I give you.

Comment: @JamesB added as answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the right API method:

```
DbxClient = new DbxClient(config, accessToken);
client.createShareableUrl(path)
```

Couldn't get any easier...

Answer (score 1):

```
DbxClient = new DbxClient(config, accessToken);
```

This call will provide you with a sharable preview Url.

```
client.createShareableUrl(path);
```

This call will provide a direct URL. The only catch is the URL will expire.

```
client.createTemporaryDirectUrl(path);
```