# Get the share image file url from dropbox -android Programatically

Tags: android, dropbox, image-uploading, dropbox-api

I am Uploading image files to Dropbox.

while uploading the images from android app to Dropbox, i want the Dropbox share Url link of each image.

then i want to save that link in local database.

Anyone Help me How to get this programatically.

my upload picture code to dropbox

MainActivity .java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity 
{
    private static final String TAG = "MY DropBox App";


    private static final String APP_KEY = "************";
    private static final String APP_SECRET = "***************";
    // You don't need to change these, leave them alone.
    private static final String ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME = "prefs";
    private static final String ACCESS_KEY_NAME = "ACCESS_KEY";
    private static final String ACCESS_SECRET_NAME = "ACCESS_SECRET";

    private static final boolean USE_OAUTH1 = false;

    DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> dropboxApi;

    private boolean mLoggedIn;

    // Android widgets
    private Button mSubmit;
    private LinearLayout mDisplay;
    private Button mPhoto;
    private Button mRoulette;

    private ImageView mImage;

    private final String PHOTO_DIR = "/Photos/MYPHOTOS/";

    private static final int NEW_PICTURE = 1;
    private String mCameraFileName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) 
        {
            mCameraFileName = savedInstanceState.getString("mCameraFileName");
        }

        // We create a new AuthSession so that we can use the Dropbox API.
        AndroidAuthSession session = buildSession();
        dropboxApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);

        // Basic Android widgets
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        checkAppKeySetup();

        mSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.auth_button);

        mSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // This logs you out if you're logged in, or vice versa
                if (mLoggedIn) {
                    logOut();
                } /*
                 * else { // Start the remote authentication if (USE_OAUTH1) {
                 * mApi.getSession().startAuthentication(DBRoulette.this); }
                 * else {
                 * mApi.getSession().startOAuth2Authentication(DBRoulette.this);
                 * } }
                 */
            }
        });

        mDisplay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.logged_in_display);

        // This is where a photo is displayed
        mImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);

        // This is the button to take a photo
        mPhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.photo_button);

        mPhoto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                // Picture from camera
                intent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                // This is not the right way to do this, but for some reason,
                // having
                // it store it in
                // MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI isn't working
                // right.

                Date date = new Date();
                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-kk-mm-ss");

                String newPicFile = df.format(date) + ".jpg";
                Log.i(TAG, newPicFile);
                String outPath = new File(Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory(), newPicFile).getPath();
                File outFile = new File(outPath);

                mCameraFileName = outFile.toString();
                Uri outuri = Uri.fromFile(outFile);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outuri);
                Log.i(TAG, "Importing New Picture: " + mCameraFileName);
                try {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, NEW_PICTURE);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    showToast("There doesn't seem to be a camera.");
                }
            }
        });

        // This is the button to Download photo
        mRoulette = (Button) findViewById(R.id.roulette_button);

        mRoulette.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DownloadRandomPicture download = new DownloadRandomPicture(
                        MainActivity.this, dropboxApi, PHOTO_DIR, mImage);
                download.execute();
            }
        });

        // Display the proper UI state if logged in or not
        setLoggedIn(dropboxApi.getSession().isLinked());

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putString("mCameraFileName", mCameraFileName);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        AndroidAuthSession session = dropboxApi.getSession();

        // The next part must be inserted in the onResume() method of the
        // activity from which session.startAuthentication() was called, so
        // that Dropbox authentication completes properly.
        if (session.authenticationSuccessful()) {
            try {
                // Mandatory call to complete the auth
                session.finishAuthentication();

                // Store it locally in our app for later use
                storeAuth(session);
                setLoggedIn(true);
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                showToast("Couldn't authenticate with Dropbox:"
                        + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                Log.i(TAG, "Error authenticating", e);
            }
        }
    }

    // This is what gets called on finishing a media piece to import
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == NEW_PICTURE) {
            // return from file upload
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri uri = null;
                if (data != null) {
                    uri = data.getData();
                }
                if (uri == null && mCameraFileName != null) {
                    uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(mCameraFileName));
                }
                File file = new File(mCameraFileName);

                if (uri != null) {
                    UploadPicture upload = new UploadPicture(this, dropboxApi,
                            PHOTO_DIR, file);
                    upload.execute();
                }
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "Unknown Activity Result from mediaImport: "
                        + resultCode);
            }
        }
    }

    private void logOut() {
        // Remove credentials from the session
        dropboxApi.getSession().unlink();

        // Clear our stored keys
        clearKeys();
        // Change UI state to display logged out version
        setLoggedIn(false);
    }

    /**
     * Convenience function to change UI state based on being logged in
     */
    private void setLoggedIn(boolean loggedIn) {
        mLoggedIn = loggedIn;
        if (loggedIn) {
            mSubmit.setText("Unlink from Dropbox");
            mDisplay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            mSubmit.setText("Link with Dropbox");
            mDisplay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mImage.setImageDrawable(null);
        }
    }

    private void checkAppKeySetup() {
        // Check to make sure that we have a valid app key
        if (APP_KEY.startsWith("CHANGE") || APP_SECRET.startsWith("CHANGE")) {
            showToast("You must apply for an app key and secret from developers.dropbox.com, and add them to the DBRoulette ap before trying it.");
            finish();
            return;
        }

        // Check if the app has set up its manifest properly.
        Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        String scheme = "db-" + APP_KEY;
        String uri = scheme + "://" + AuthActivity.AUTH_VERSION + "/test";
        testIntent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        if (0 == pm.queryIntentActivities(testIntent, 0).size()) {
            showToast("URL scheme in your app's "
                    + "manifest is not set up correctly. You should have a "
                    + "com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity with the "
                    + "scheme: " + scheme);
            finish();
        }
    }

    private void showToast(String msg) {
        Toast error = Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        error.show();
    }

    /**
     * Shows keeping the access keys returned from Trusted Authenticator in a
     * local store, rather than storing user name & password, and
     * re-authenticating each time (which is not to be done, ever).
     */
    private void loadAuth(AndroidAuthSession session) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, 0);
        String key = "oauth2:";
        String secret = "**************";
        if (key == null || secret == null || key.length() == 0
                || secret.length() == 0)
            return;

        if (key.equals("oauth2:")) {
            // If the key is set to "oauth2:", then we can assume the token is
            // for OAuth 2.
            session.setOAuth2AccessToken(secret);
        } else {
            // Still support using old OAuth 1 tokens.
            session.setAccessTokenPair(new AccessTokenPair(key, secret));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Shows keeping the access keys returned from Trusted Authenticator in a
     * local store, rather than storing user name & password, and
     * re-authenticating each time (which is not to be done, ever).
     */
    private void storeAuth(AndroidAuthSession session) {
        // Store the OAuth 2 access token, if there is one.
        String oauth2AccessToken = "****************";
        if (oauth2AccessToken != null) {
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME,
                    0);
            Editor edit = prefs.edit();
            edit.putString(ACCESS_KEY_NAME, "oauth2:");
            edit.putString(ACCESS_SECRET_NAME, oauth2AccessToken);
            edit.commit();
            return;
        }
        // Store the OAuth 1 access token, if there is one. This is only
        // necessary if
        // you're still using OAuth 1.
        AccessTokenPair oauth1AccessToken = session.getAccessTokenPair();
        if (oauth1AccessToken != null) {
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME,
                    0);
            Editor edit = prefs.edit();
            edit.putString(ACCESS_KEY_NAME, oauth1AccessToken.key);
            edit.putString(ACCESS_SECRET_NAME, oauth1AccessToken.secret);
            edit.commit();
            return;
        }
    }

    private void clearKeys() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, 0);
        Editor edit = prefs.edit();
        edit.clear();
        edit.commit();
    }

    private AndroidAuthSession buildSession() {
        AppKeyPair appKeyPair = new AppKeyPair(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);

        AndroidAuthSession session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeyPair);
        loadAuth(session);
        return session;
    }
}
```

UploadPicture .java

```
public class UploadPicture extends AsyncTask<Void, Long, Boolean> {

    private DropboxAPI<?> mApi;
    private String mPath;
    private File mFile;

    private long mFileLen;
    private UploadRequest mRequest;
    private Context mContext;
    private final ProgressDialog mDialog;

    private String mErrorMsg;


    public UploadPicture(Context context, DropboxAPI<?> api, String dropboxPath,
            File file) {
        // We set the context this way so we don't accidentally leak activities
        mContext = context.getApplicationContext();

        mFileLen = file.length();
        mApi = api;
        mPath = dropboxPath;
        mFile = file;

        mDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        mDialog.setMax(100);
        mDialog.setMessage("Uploading " + file.getName());
        mDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mDialog.setProgress(0);
        mDialog.setButton(ProgressDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Cancel", new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // This will cancel the putFile operation
                mRequest.abort();
            }
        });
        mDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            // By creating a request, we get a handle to the putFile operation,
            // so we can cancel it later if we want to
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(mFile);
            String path = mPath + mFile.getName();
            mRequest = mApi.putFileOverwriteRequest(path, fis, mFile.length(),new ProgressListener()
            {
                @Override
                public long progressInterval()
                {
                    // Update the progress bar every half-second or so
                    return 500;
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgress(long bytes, long total) 
                {
                    publishProgress(bytes);
                }
            });

            if (mRequest != null) 
            {

                mRequest.upload();
                return true;
            }




        } catch (DropboxUnlinkedException e) {
            // This session wasn't authenticated properly or user unlinked
            mErrorMsg = "This app wasn't authenticated properly.";
        } catch (DropboxFileSizeException e) {
            // File size too big to upload via the API
            mErrorMsg = "This file is too big to upload";
        } catch (DropboxPartialFileException e) {
            // We canceled the operation
            mErrorMsg = "Upload canceled";
        } catch (DropboxServerException e) {
            // Server-side exception.  These are examples of what could happen,
            // but we don't do anything special with them here.
            if (e.error == DropboxServerException._401_UNAUTHORIZED) {
                // Unauthorized, so we should unlink them.  You may want to
                // automatically log the user out in this case.
            } else if (e.error == DropboxServerException._403_FORBIDDEN) {
                // Not allowed to access this
            } else if (e.error == DropboxServerException._404_NOT_FOUND) {
                // path not found (or if it was the thumbnail, can't be
                // thumbnailed)
            } else if (e.error == DropboxServerException._507_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE) {
                // user is over quota
            } else {
                // Something else
            }
            // This gets the Dropbox error, translated into the user's language
            mErrorMsg = e.body.userError;
            if (mErrorMsg == null) {
                mErrorMsg = e.body.error;
            }
        } catch (DropboxIOException e) {
            // Happens all the time, probably want to retry automatically.
            mErrorMsg = "Network error.  Try again.";
        } catch (DropboxParseException e) {
            // Probably due to Dropbox server restarting, should retry
            mErrorMsg = "Dropbox error.  Try again.";
        } catch (DropboxException e) {
            // Unknown error
            mErrorMsg = "Unknown error.  Try again.";
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Long... progress) {
        int percent = (int)(100.0*(double)progress[0]/mFileLen + 0.5);
        mDialog.setProgress(percent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        mDialog.dismiss();
        if (result) {
            showToast("Image successfully uploaded");
        } else {
            showToast(mErrorMsg);
        }
    }

    private void showToast(String msg) {
        Toast error = Toast.makeText(mContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        error.show();
    }
```

Comment: Share your existing code ,what you have done till now. So that someone can enhance it for you.

Comment: Check out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942371/getting-file-url-from-a-dropbox-file-with-dropbox-api

Comment: in this link iam not getting any code

Comment: Check Out : https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/retrieve-info.html#RetrieveFileInfo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to modify UploadPicture class:

1. Extract field from this variable:

   ```
   String path = mPath + mFile.getName();
   ```
2. Put this snippet into **onPostExecute** method in upload successful case:

   ```
   DropboxAPI.Entry filesInPath = mApi.metadata(path, 1, null, true, null);

   // Basing on provided code, only one file is uploaded
   DropboxAPI.Entry uploadedFile = entries.contents.get(0);

   String shareUrl = mApi.share(uploadedFile.path).url;
   ```

After this manipulations **shareUrl** variable will contain sharing link for the image.

Comment: What about the new API, i.e, Dropbox API v2?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [`share`](https://www.dropboxstatic.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.5.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#share(java.lang.String)).